# Google maps with html 5 watchposition (prevent maps refresh)

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have created a very simple html 5 watchposition with google maps api v3 which tracking the user location. I have lat, long and accuracy in my watchposition. Everything work well but just 1 problem. When i testing in Android phone browser and IOS phone browser, the google maps keep refreshing if watchPosition() detect a new location (lat, long, acc).

My question is why not only the marker moves instead of refreshing the entire maps?

i do not have the script right now but it is just a simple script that can find any way online.

Comment: Providing the script or a link to the map on a web server is needed to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward:

The declaration of `map` should be outside the `onsuccess` event of `watchposition`